# Applications of the fact that $\int_{p/a}^{q/a}\frac{f(ax)}{x}\,dx$ is independent of $a$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've come across the integration idea $\displaystyle\int_{p/a}^{q/a}\frac{f(ax)}{x}\,dx$ is independent of the value of $a$. I've been able to prove this by using a substituting of $u=ax$, however, I'm not entirely sure if there's a practical application of this when trying to evaluate an integral. Are there any occasions where this can be used? Are there any integrals that would otherwise be impossible/difficult to evaluate without this? Or is this just a novel idea?

Comment: Yes, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{x} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$